# Ubuntu 14.10 system startup is less verbose

Tags: boot, 14.10, plymouth

Booting Trusty Tahr without splash screen produced lots of `Starting <service name here>...` messages, which I actually liked, as I could track the booting process.

With Utopic Unicorn, I get much less of these messages, while I still have many services installed. (E.g. I don't even see 'Starting ssh...' or 'Waiting for network configuration...'.)

Probably these messages are there, but disappear too fast due to a clear screen or something? How can I re-enable verbose system bootup?

Maybe it's something to do with plymouth config, but I'm not sure.